# How to make button and textbox in one row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I us bootstrap 3.3.7 in my project.

I have this html code:

```
<div id="savedQueryEditor" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Existing queries
                <a class="pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></i></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label>Enter new name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="savedQueryFilter" />
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="saveCurrentQuery" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32160/).

My question is how to make both elements(button and text box)in one row?

Comment: Fiddle isn't a link???

Comment: @ArjanKnol, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your form controls with `.form-inline` (see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline):

```
    <div class="panel-body form-inline">
        <label>Enter new name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="savedQueryFilter" />
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="saveCurrentQuery" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ablewhite/pen/wdowLP

Comment: Can you please add fiddle?

Comment: Try this updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32163/.  Note that part of the problem was you were referencing Bootstrap v3.0.0, not 3.3.7 (links updated in Fiddle).

Comment: Also - just in case you wanted the label to appear above the field - try https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32164/.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the input having a `width:100%;` if you remove that like this:

```
.form-control {
   width:auto !important;
}
```

It should work, here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32161/)

Comment: This was down to Bootstrap v3.0.0 being referenced instead of 3.3.7 - once the CSS is brought up-to-date, wrapping it with a `.form-inline` applies `width: auto`.

Comment: @Conan Good spot!